# Migrate to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, migration

Is it sensible for me to migrate to QGIS?

I've been using [OCAD](https://www.ocad.com/en/downloads/freeware), a very old vector based map software to maintain a local "back country" map.

With OCAD6 I initially import base data, e.g. contours, main roads etc, as `.dxf`. Later import new data the same way. But then I can adjust or draw things easily by hand.

As tracks wash away, get re-routed, get abandoned, or repaired, I can easily update track condition freehand, from, say, "abandoned" to "Grade 3".

I can simply cut a line object to create 2 new line objects. Or make 2 cuts to create a new section in the middle. Then change that section from, e.g., "grade 4 track" to "grade 2 track" by:-

- selecting the new line object
- selecting a new symbol
- click "change symbol".

Any way to do this easily in QGIS?

Am I misunderstanding what QGIS & GIS in general are?

Comment: Can you add information about what data format do you use? Do you use dxf just to import the data into this software? Or do you store the data in dxf as well?

Comment: The data format used by OCAD is it's own proprietory one. It will import & export .dxf.I just mentioned the vector format because OCAD has the look'n'feel of a raster drawing program, so much detail can be changed on the spot by hand.   So migrating to QGIS via exporting vectors isn't a problem, but actually using QGIS might be.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any obstacles for you to use QGIS instead of OCAD.

Editing works pretty much the same way you do. QGIS has a `CAD Tools` plugin for those who prefer CAD-like techniques.

You will benefit from the ability to load other data and maps in the background to check your data visually, without the need to do a complete re-import.

Answer (score 3):

If you want migrate from OCAD on some free & open-source software then highly recommend you **OpenOrienteering Mapper** (OOMapper for short) - cartographic desktop publishing software for creating and printing maps (distributed with symbol sets for orienteering maps, but other symbol sets could be created in easy way directly in OOMapper).

OpenOrienteering Mapper's site - http://www.openorienteering.org/apps/mapper/

As advantage of migrating on OOMapper from OCAD:

- Open Source: The program is completely free, every programmer can improve it.
- Cross-platform: The program works on Android, Windows, macOS and Linux.
- Symbol sets for ISOM2000 (forest), ISSOM2007 (sprint), ISMTBOM (mountain bike), ISSkiOM (ski), and for course design and control description sheets
- Import and export of ocd maps and symbol sets (import: version 6 - 12, export: version 8)
- Georeferencing (based on Proj.4 library)
- Working with various kinds of templates:

  - Images (bmp, jpg, tif, png, gif)
  - GPS tracks (gpx)
  - Vector data (dxf, osm, shp)
  - Maps (ocd, omap, xmap)
  - Georeferencing of templates by world file
- Working with all important symbol types:

  - Points
  - Lines
  - Areas
  - Text
  - Composite symbols
- Drawing and many editing tools for objects
- Printing, PDF and raster image export for getting the map into course setting programs:

  - Overprinting simulation (raster output)
  - CMYK PDF export (vector output)
- Many translations

At this point OpenOrienteering Mapper is free & open-source alternative to OCAD. So, *if you already has some own created maps in `.ocd` (OCAD) or `.dxf` format you could easy open this map for editing in OOMapper* too!

Answer (score 2):

I have with success migrated companies from CAD (and commercial GIS) software to QGIS. The main challenge is having people understand the database behind a GIS instead of (just) a CAD drawing. Usually DXF is no problem opening in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I would describe OCAD as 'very old vector based map software'. It's been around since the late 1980s but is now on version 12 and is capable of producing very sophisticated map artwork. It is of course commercial software but then if cartographers require software to adapt to changing times and technology, then we may expect to pay someone to do this :)